# Como puedo sacarle el link a una película?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, web, app

Es que estoy desarrollando una web parecida a peliplus , donde poner peliculas y asi , y cada vez que cojo algun enlace de una pelicula lo bloquean al instante, creo que a de ser por la encriptación, habra alguna otra forma , o algun alojamiento de video gratuito .

Comment: Debes dar más detalles, a lo menos comentar de donde consigues el enlace y un ejemplo del mismo

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: No uses enlaces de terceros ni descargues películas sin autorización, eso infringe derechos de autor seriamente y se considera un **delito** en casi todas las jurisdicciones, si lo haces, lo más probable es que te tumben el sitio y enfrentes **cargos penales**. Las plataformas como Amazon, Netlifx, etc mantienen acuerdos y contratos con las productoras para poder transmitir ese contenido en sus plataformas.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!, probablemente el enlace se bloquee porque no estás autorizado para usarlo, pero puedes usar el alojamiento gratuito de Storage de Firebase, es un bucket el cual te permitirá subir todos tus archivos, pero te reitero que no lo uses para piratería porque los términos y condiciones Google se toma la libertad de cerrarte el proyecto si te descubren

Firebase tiene su SDK(Software Developer Kit) que te puede ayudar a hacer la página con su sistema de usuario, base datos basada en documentos y más características, te invito a aprender a usarlo.

¡Espero haberte ayudado, Feliz hacking!

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta 